# Como calcular meses de um ano a partir de um número decimal?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\tPrograma para saber quanto demora a tornar-se génio!\n\n");
    float tempo(int horas);
    float converter(float x);
    int num_horas;
    float dias,anos;
    printf("Quantas horas vai dedicar por dia para ser genio?");
    scanf("%d",&num_horas);
    dias=tempo(num_horas);
    anos=converter(dias);
    printf("Voce vai demorar %.1f dias ou seja aproximadamente %.2f anos para ficar génio",dias,anos);
    return 0;
}
//funcao para converter dias em anos
float converter(float x) {
if(x>366) {
    int um_ano=366;
    float troca=x/um_ano;
    return troca;
}
}
//funcao que converte as horas dedicadas em dias;
float tempo(int horas) {
    float dias;
    dias=10000/horas;
    return dias;

}
```

O código funciona, mas eu queria o melhorar naquela parte quando faz `printf` e diz quantos anos leva para ser gênio. Ele faz um `float`(de propósito), mas eu queria converter a parte decimal em meses. Por exemplo 4.22 anos ou seja queria que ficasse 4 ano e não sei quantos meses(.22).

Aceito críticas construtivas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz o que entendi. Obviamente ele não é muito preciso, pode dar resultados estranhos em alguns casos, mas só para um exercício está bom.

Tem várias coisas que poderiam ser melhoradas em um contexto específico. Como é exercício, ter as funções pode fazer sentido, mas para fazer algo tão simples que só será usado uma vez, não faz sentido tê-las.

Note os pequenos detalhes que eu reescrevi para ficar mais organizado, veja como fica mais fácil de ler e mais enxuto. Poderia ser mais ainda. Tem variável sobrando. Note que dei nomes melhores para as funções, assim não precisa de comentários. Arrumei outros pequenos defeitos.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float converterDiasEmAnos(float dias) {
    return dias / 365;
}
float converterHorasEmDias(int horas) {
    return 10000 / horas;
}
int obterMeses(float anos) {
    return (anos - (int)anos) / (1.0f / 12.0f) + 1;
}
int main() {
    printf("\tPrograma para saber quanto demora a tornar-se genio!\n\n");
    int num_horas;
    printf("Quantas horas vai dedicar por dia para ser genio? ");
    scanf("%d", &num_horas);
    float dias = converterHorasEmDias(num_horas);
    float anos = converterDiasEmAnos(dias);
    int meses = obterMeses(anos);
    printf("\nVoce vai demorar %.1f dias, ou seja, aproximadamente %d anos e %d meses para ficar genio", dias, (int)anos, meses);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jIfaTz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kphihrqh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ConvertHours.c).

Comment: Podes explicar esta parte? (1.0f / 12.0f) + 1; Nao entendi muito bem. De resto esta ok.

Comment: Esta parte é só matemática, não tem nada de programação, fiz o que você pediu, transformar decimal em meses, só somei 1 para arredondar pra cima e não criar uma expectativa que o tempo seria inferior ao que realmente é.