# O que daria para simplificar em um código assim?

Tags: c, algoritmo, otimização

Eu fiz um programa, com base num estudo que li. O estudo diz que são precisas 10 mil horas para ficar génio/mestre em qualquer área.

Dá para simplificar o que eu fiz? No menu só consegui fazer assim, se me derem sugestões eu agradeço. Tenho imensa vontade de aprender e ideias para complexar o programa também são bem vindas.

Aqui deixo o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
float converterDiasEmAnos(float dias) {
    return dias/365;
}
float converterHorasEmDias(int horas) {
    return 10000/horas;
}
int obterMeses(float anos) {
    return (anos -(int)anos)*(12);
}

int main()
{

    //prototipos
    float converterDiasEmAnos(float dias);
    float converterHorasEmDias(int horas);
    int obterMeses(float anos);
    printf("\t\tPrograma para saber quanto demora a tornar-se génio!\n\n");
    //variaveis locais
    int num_horas,meses,escolha;
    float anos,dias;
    //MENU
    printf("\nDigite a opcao correta:\n1-Continuar com o programa\n0-Para sair!\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&escolha);
    switch(escolha) {
        case 1:
            //pergunta
            printf("Quantas horas vai dedicar por dia para ser génio?");
            scanf("%d",&num_horas);
            //chamada
            dias=converterHorasEmDias(num_horas);
            anos=converterDiasEmAnos(dias);
            meses=obterMeses(anos);
            //afirmacao
            printf("Voce vai demorar %.0f dias ou seja aproximadamente %.0f anos\n%d meses para ficar génio\n",dias,anos,meses);
            break;
        case 0:
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Digite corretamente!");
            break;

    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Existe algum erro no código?

Comment: Olá, @Miguel. Editei sua pergunta para acertar um pouco a indentação do código, e tirar a formatação em HTML que você usou. Para saber como formatar uma postagem, veja este link: [Ajuda do Markdown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Para ver as mudanças feitas, basta olhar o [Histórico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/106372/revisions) de edições. Se quiser [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes para sabermos onde é que você precisa de ajuda, neste link tem umas dicas: "[Ask]".

Comment: Sugestao: usa sempre `double` para valores de virgula flutuante. Nao ha vantagem em usar `float`.

Comment: Sugestao: normalmente os prototipos poem-se fora de qualquer funcao, logo a seguir aos includes. Pondo os prototipos dentro duma funcao eles so se aplicam a essa funcao; se tiveres outras funcoes no teu programa, tens que repetir (desnecessariamente) os prototipos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Na sua [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106329/101) eu já tinha dado uma boa organizada no código, agora está pior de novo. Não tem muito o que simplificar, só dá para organizar melhor.

Um dos erros que você comete é não manter a consistência. Hora usa de um jeito e hora usa de outro. Hora organiza, hora amontoa tudo. Hora usa cosias desnecessárias. Preste atenção caractere por caractere do que eu escrevi para ver como fica melhor.

O que eu "simplifiquei":

Tirei os protótipos, eles só são necessários em três situações: a) vai usar em outro arquivo, b) há referências circulares entres as funções ou c) o código está desorganizado demais. Como não há nenhum desses casos nesse código, eu os retirei (já havia feito antes na pergunta anterior).

Tirei as declarações de variáveis separadas, isso é estilo antigo e desnecessário. As declarações devem estar mais perto possível do seu uso. Tem que diminuir o escopo na medida do possível.

Tirei os comentários porque eles não estão sendo úteis para nada. Comentários devem explicar porque fez algo que parece estranho e não dizer o que o código faz. Há mitos sobre o [uso de comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15566/101). Se acha que um trecho de código merece um comentário, ou ele está confuso ou ele merece estar em uma função separada. Preferi não separar o menu, mas é uma possibilidade.

Um dos motivos de eu não ter mexido no menu é que me parece que o código está pela metade. Esse menu não parece fazer sentido algum. Se for pra simplificar mesmo, do jeito que está eu só tiraria ele. Não tirei porque acho que vai fazer algo útil com ele depois. Se não fizer, basta tirá-lo. Não coloque nada no código que não acrescente algo realmente útil para a experiência do usuário. No momento ele só causa transtorno.

Tirei uma declaração de variável. No outra pergunta eu tinha dito que ela era desnecessária, mas tinha deixado porque ele poderia servir para alguma coisa caso mexesse no código. Fiz agora para simplificar.

Tirei um `break` depois de do `return`, ele nunca seria executado. Na verdade era para tirar outras coisas redundantes, mas aí o `switch` todo teria que ser tirado porque ele não tem função nenhum no código. E finalmente a mensagem de menu também teria que ser tirada.

Obviamente fica difícil fazer um *code review* em código que está pela metade. Na próxima vez que pedir isso, apresente um código completo, mesmo que tenha que apresentar só um trecho.

```
#include <stdio.h>
float converterDiasEmAnos(float dias) {
    return dias / 365;
}
float converterHorasEmDias(int horas) {
    return 10000 / horas;
}
int obterMeses(float anos) {
    return (anos - (int)anos) * 12;
}
int main() {
    printf("\t\tPrograma para saber quanto demora a tornar-se génio!\n\n");
    int escolha;
    printf("\nDigite a opcao correta:\n1-Continuar com o programa\n0-Para sair!\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &escolha);
    switch(escolha) {
        case 1:
            int num_horas;
            printf("Quantas horas vai dedicar por dia para ser genio?");
            scanf("%d", &num_horas);
            float dias = converterHorasEmDias(num_horas);
            float anos = converterDiasEmAnos(dias);
            printf("Voce vai demorar %.0f dias ou seja aproximadamente %.0f anos\n%d meses para ficar genio\n", dias, anos, obterMeses(anos));
            break;
        case 0:
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("Digite corretamente!");
            break;
    }
}
```

Vou colocar aqui o código mais simplificado tirando as partes inúteis. Você pode não gostar, mas estou fazendo o que pede a pergunta, tirar tudo que é inútil simplifica o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
float converterDiasEmAnos(float dias) {
    return dias / 365;
}
float converterHorasEmDias(int horas) {
    return 10000 / horas;
}
int obterMeses(float anos) {
    return (anos - (int)anos) * 12;
}
int main() {
    printf("\t\tPrograma para saber quanto demora a tornar-se génio!\n\n");
    int num_horas;
    printf("Quantas horas vai dedicar por dia para ser genio?");
    scanf("%d", &num_horas);
    float dias = converterHorasEmDias(num_horas);
    float anos = converterDiasEmAnos(dias);
    printf("Voce vai demorar %.0f dias ou seja aproximadamente %.0f anos\n%d meses para ficar genio\n", dias, anos, obterMeses(anos));
}
```

Uma última simplificação já que as funções estão sendo usadas só uma vez. Eu sei que pode estar querendo usar para outras coisas, mas nesse caso não está sendo necessário ter funções e simplificar costuma ser eliminar tudo o que não precisa ser usado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("\t\tPrograma para saber quanto demora a tornar-se génio!\n\n");
    int num_horas;
    printf("Quantas horas vai dedicar por dia para ser genio?");
    scanf("%d", &num_horas);
    float dias = num_horas / 365;
    float anos = 10000 / dias;
    printf("Voce vai demorar %.0f dias ou seja aproximadamente %.0f anos\n%d meses para ficar genio\n", dias, anos, (anos - (int)anos) * 12);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mpRzAz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tizkdqny-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Simplification.c).

Simplificação pode dar mais legibilidade, mas pode piorá-la também. Eu poderia fazer outras que certamente pioraria. Algumas que eu fiz pode ter piorado dependendo do contexto. Olhando só para este código não piorou. Ele é bem compreensível, mas poderia não ser em um contexto maior.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54213/discussion-on-answer-by-bigown-simplificar-codigo)

Comment: Eu acho que o menu era para estar num loop (`while(true) {...`, daí a opção de sair do programa e as funções. É bem comum esse tipo de menu em exemplos de programas para iniciantes =)